# Rearrange time series in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have created a ggplot matrix of 25 time series. Now I would like to rearrange time series, such that **wheat** is next to **rice** ...
Here is my code:

```
     data_std <- data
        for (i in 2:26)
        {data_std[,i] <- (data_std[,i] - mean(data_std[,i])) / sd(data_std[,i])}


        # Create the new dataframe "datalili"
        newdata_wheat <- data_std[,1:2]
        names(newdata_wheat)[2]<-paste("price")
        newdata_wheat["commodity"] <- "wheat"
        datalili <- newdata_wheat


for (i in 3:26)
{ data_new <- data_std[,c(1,i)]
 names(data_new)[2]<-paste("price")

com <- colnames(data_std)[i]
 data_new["commodity"] <- com
 datalili = rbind(datalili,data_new)}

# Plot
ggplot(datalili, aes(x=time, y=price, group=commodity, colour='red')) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ commodity)
```

In my result, ob. were rearranged alphabetically, yet I would like to arrange them such that the following order holds: c(1,2,3,4,5,6,24,25,2,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,20,23)

I have tried:

```
ggplot(datalili, aes(x=time, y=price, group=commodity, colour='red'), **layout=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,24,25,2,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,20,23)**) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ commodity) but it did not work out.
```

Thank you in advance!

Here is the current version of my plot:

http://127.0.0.1:9611/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=1192&height=697

Comment: turn `commodity` into factor and define its levels manually

Comment: What would be the appropriate code to that ? factor("wheat", "rice",.. ?

Comment: something like `datalili$commodity <- factor(datalili$commodity, levels = c("wheat", "rice", ...))`